# When creating a service in C# code, do you absolutely have to use asp.net web service application?

Tags: c#-4.0, service, web, project

When creating a service in C# code, do you absolutely have to use asp.net web service application? Is it possible to use asp.net web application and then add service.asmx later to the project ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add asp.net your web service to asp.net web application project after you created your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
Is it applicable to framework 4.0 that is visual studio 2010 ?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the framework version. You can easily check by trying to add as new web service from Visual Studio.